# How to add character to the end of the output lines by not adding to the last line?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to add comma (,) to all the lines in output except for the last line of output in Oracle SQL?

Sample Query which i am working on

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHR(39) || ltrim(MATNR,0) || CHR(39) AS GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST
FROM PR1_SOAINFRA.WLI_NESOA2_REPORTING_ARCHIVE,  
    XMLTABLE( '/_-GLB_-OGTX_DESADV01_CUST_ASN/IDOC/E1EDK08/E1EDP07/E1EDP09'  
              PASSING XMLTYPE(data_value,871)  
              COLUMNS  
              MATNR varchar2(2000) path 'MATNR'  
            ) 
WHERE ERRORCODE IS NOT NULL AND BUSINESSID = '0000000382153210-E9APRR3103';
```

Output:

```
'12352682'  
'12351436'  
'12351434'  
'12350683'
```

Desired Output (no comma at end of the last line):

```
'12352682',  
'12351436',  
'12351434',  
'12350683'
```

Comment: Will there be rows with duplicate values?

Comment: Do you need the output as a single value or list of values?

Comment: see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d0869/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as a separate answer, subquery will order the numbers and outer query will append comma based on rownum and return result in desc order

```
select GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST || case when rownum > 1 then ',' else '' end as GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT CHR(39) || ltrim(MATNR,0) || CHR(39) AS GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST
    FROM PR1_SOAINFRA.WLI_NESOA2_REPORTING_ARCHIVE,  
        XMLTABLE( '/_-GLB_-OGTX_DESADV01_CUST_ASN/IDOC/E1EDK08/E1EDP07/E1EDP09'  
              PASSING XMLTYPE(data_value,871)  
              COLUMNS  
              MATNR varchar2(2000) path 'MATNR'  
            ) 
    WHERE ERRORCODE IS NOT NULL AND BUSINESSID = '0000000382153210-E9APRR3103'
    order by GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST
) e order by GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST DESC
```

SQL Fiddle

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table nums(
  id number(10)
);

insert into nums values ('12352682');
insert into nums values ('12351436');
insert into nums values ('12351434');
insert into nums values ('12350683');
```

**Query**:

```
select 
num || case when rownum > 1 then ',' else '' end as num
from (
select chr(39) || id  || chr(39) as num
from nums 
order by num
) e order by num desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c38c/2/0)**:

```
|         NUM |
|-------------|
| '12352682', |
| '12351436', |
| '12351434', |
| '12350683'  |
```

Comment: Thank you @Saravana: Many thanks for this thought using CASE statement. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to prepend a comma to every line but the first one...

```
select distinct case when rownum > 1 then ',' end ||
       globe_material_id_list
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT CHR(39) || ltrim(MATNR,0) || CHR(39) AS GLOBE_MATERIAL_ID_LIST
    FROM PR1_SOAINFRA.WLI_NESOA2_REPORTING_ARCHIVE,  
        XMLTABLE( '/_-GLB_-OGTX_DESADV01_CUST_ASN/IDOC/E1EDK08/E1EDP07/E1EDP09'  
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(data_value,871)  
                  COLUMNS  
                  MATNR varchar2(2000) path 'MATNR'  
                ) 
    WHERE ERRORCODE IS NOT NULL AND BUSINESSID = '0000000382153210-E9APRR3103'
);
```

This has to be an inline query because of your `distinct`: you need to generate the set of `globe_material_id_list` before formatting it.

Comment: see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d0869/19 to ignore append for last row, used desc order by in subquery and order by in outer query

Comment: @Saravana - you should post that as a separate answer: it meets the OP's requirement more closely, although I think two sorts could be expensive for what is basically a cosmetic effect.

Comment: Thank You APC for the response. It helps me a lot to manipulate and apply it in different sections of my code.